# Using java classes in Play framework with Scala to be returned as Json Object

Tags: java, scala, playframework, writable

I have some java classes which were generated using axis wsdl2java. I want to use those classes to be returned in Json format, but i keep getting various error, such as `cannot convert Incident Object to HttpResponse try to make it writable`.

When tried using **`Writable`** it asks me to check if it have **`apply`** method.

Is there any swift way i can use java classes as is, without going through hassle of making it case classes.

Comment: Is your problem that you need an easy way to generate Play json `Writes`/`Format` for a Java class?

Comment: Yes basically I was trying to respond it in Json format with chunked data. So that client doesn’t have to wait h till all the data has been passed on to him as a response.

Comment: I believe that neither play-json nor circe will work with Java classes, unless you write a custom `Writes` or `Encoder`. Perhaps this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388589/scala-equivalent-to-wsdl2java

Answer (score 1):

You try to render a class directly with `Ok(MyClass())` and this is not possible. You have to render it as `Json` or `String` or any Writable. `Json` is probably the best choice. You should use a library like play-json, circe or one of the several others and render you response with `Ok(Json.toJson(Myclass()))` (for play-json) or equivalent.

Comment: trying to do something like this . `val source = Source.apply[Incident](incidentsList.asScala.toList)
    Ok.chunked(source)`. Will it work with the above suggestion you mentioned. Forgive my lack of knowledge. just a new bie

Comment: First you will have to add a json library to your dependencies in your build.sbt file. After you will have to write a json writer for the type of source. Do you really want to chunk your response?

Comment: i tried without the chunked format as well. But it is bit too much to write as json writer for that class, since it contains around 60+ attributes to that class. Dont we have anything like Gson library for scala.

Comment: If you use circe you have nothing to write and just to add one import. If you use play-json you only need to write implicit val myImplicitRead: OFormat[MyClass] =  Json.format[MyClass] But with play-json I think that you will have a problem cause your class has more than 22 attributes (known problem).